# A surjective function from $\mathbb R $ to a compact metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

If X is a compact metric space then,there exists a surjective function $\mathbb R \to X$ 
I think the above statement is false. But I can't think of a counter example.
Any help?

Comment: Are you looking for a **continuous** function?

Comment: No, I am no looking for continuous function.

Comment: I suggest you read about the [Hahn–Mazurkiewicz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#The_Hahn%E2%80%93Mazurkiewicz_theorem).

Answer (score 4):

Any continuous image of $\Bbb R$ is (path-)connected. So no such function exists for $\{0,1\}$ (which is finite, so compact) or the Cantor set e.g.

If the function need not be continuous, then note that any compact metric space has size at most $|\Bbb R|$, being separable. So then one *can* do it.

Comment: The OP doesn't ask for a **continuous** function

Comment: I am not looking for continuous function. It can be arbitrary surjection function.

Comment: @simutiyam See my updated answer

Comment: Why does compact metric space have size at most |R| ?

Comment: @simutiyam A compact metric space is separable. A separable metric space has size at most $|\Bbb R|$.